# Evaluate boolean expressions from arrayList

Tags: java, optimization, boolean-operations, javascript-engine

I generate a truth table from any boolean expression and store it into a 2D array. As a first step, I store my boolean expression in an object arrayList. I count noumbers of variables to deduct numbers of columns(variables) and numbers of rows(combinaisons).

```
    nbrVariables = variables.size();
    nbrCombinaisons =  (int)Math.pow(2,variables.size());   
    truth_table = new int [nbrCombinaisons][nbrVariables+1];
```

I declare **nbrVariables+1** because I need 1 column which represents my output. Using a loop, I generate each combinaisons of my truth table.

I have this in my console :

```
---- Equation  : [soccer, +, food]
---- Variables : [soccer, food]

variables : 2
combinaisons : 4

header : [food, soccer]

[0, 0, null]
[0, 1, null]
[1, 0, null]
[1, 1, null]
```

As you can see, each elements of my last columns is null. To complete this column which represents my output, I need to evaluate my boolean expression for each of this combinaisons. I reiterate that my boolean expression is a arrayList of Objects.

To complete it, I use a string buffer to use a script that evaluate my boolean expression for each combinaisons(=each row).

```
public void getOutput() throws ScriptException{

        StringBuffer sbExpr = new StringBuffer();
        temp= new ArrayList<Object>();
        temp.addAll(equation);

        for(int i=0; i<=nbrCombinaisons-1; i++){
            for (int j=0;  j<=nbrVariables-1 ; j++){
                if(equation.contains(variables.get(j).getName())){
                    temp.set(equation.indexOf(variables.get(j).getName()), truth_table[i][j]);

                }
            }
            truth_table[i][nbrVariables]= getResult(temp, sbExpr );

        }
    }

public int getResult(ArrayList<Object> temp, StringBuffer sbExpr) throws ScriptException{

        sbExpr.delete(0, sbExpr.length());       
        for(int i =0; i< temp.size(); i++){
            if(temp.get(i).equals(1)){
                sbExpr.append("1");
            }else if(temp.get(i).equals(0)){
                sbExpr.append("0");
            }else if(temp.get(i).getClass().equals(String.class))
                switch((String)temp.get(i))
                {
                    case "+": 
                        sbExpr.append("|");
                        break; 
                    case ".": 
                        sbExpr.append("&");
                        break; 
                    case "¤": 
                        sbExpr.append("^");
                        break; 
                    case "!": 
                        sbExpr.append("!");
                        break; 
                    case "(": 
                        sbExpr.append("(");
                        break; 
                    case ")": 
                        sbExpr.append(")");
                        break; 
                    default: 
                        System.out.println("no match"); 
                } 
        }
//      System.out.println("\nsbExpr -----> " +sbExpr );    

        ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine se = sem.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        if (se.eval(sbExpr.toString()).toString().equals("1")){
           return 1;
        }else{
           return 0;
       }
    }
```

Well this works fine.

```
[PCU, Fuel circuit]

[0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

But I would like to know if there is an other way to do it because this way is, for me, not very sexy. It is heavy and more I have variables, more it is long. Also, I am asking me if using script can be use in other computer if I want share my application.

Thank you for yout help

Comment: Why do you generate a script rather than evaluating the expression directly?

Comment: Because I do not know how to do it from an ArrayList... :/

Comment: Why not use an `ArrayList<Boolean>`?

Comment: Even if I use an **ArrayList<Boolean>** , I will need to parse my expression boolean which is into my ArrayList<Object> and identify which columns are which variables. Well, to be honset, at the beginning, my 2D array was  typed HashMap<String, Boolean> . But I was due to create for each element, an HashMap. Too gourmet. So I prefer work with Integer and try to identify it. Furthermore, I want implements Quine Mc Cluskey method to minmise any boolean expression. To do that, I will use an 2D array with integer to work easly. But thats is an other issue ahaha. Thanks